# How to use ssml tags in textToSpeech for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I use @ionic-native/text-to-speech for text to speech in my app. Ionic uses this plugin: https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts

I want to use ssml tags in my text:

```
const options: any = {
    text: '<speak>I like <sub alias="pizza">rotten eggs</sub></speak>',
    locale: 'en-US',
    rate: 1.0
};

this.tts.speak(options)
.then(() => {
    // do anything
})
.catch((error: any) => {
    // do anything
});
```

.

*The problem:*

With **Google's** text to speech it ignores the ssml tags. So, it speaks:

> I like rotten eggs.

Text to speech on **iOS** reads out everything:

> < speak >I like < sub alias="pizza" >rotten eggs< /sub>< /speak>

Does someone know what do I have to change to get a correct pronounciation?

Answer (score 2):

Since...

1. The Cordova plugin simply uses whatever text-to-speech engine the device happens to have on it, and...
2. Text-to-speech pronunciation differs depending on the engine and isn't modifiable via code... at least not on Android...

I don't see how it's going to be possible for you to control pronunciation in any way other than parsing and "pre-correcting" the Strings yourself based on the platform it's running on (not realistic or practical).

Unless... you're OK with using cloud-based speech, in which case Google cloud text to speech does accept ssml.

Comment: Okay, that's a pitty. Thanks for your suggestion. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Hi, did you find anything on it yet? I am into a similar situation and need the regular text for AVSpeechUtterance.